# Fetching Large Amount of Data in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making an web app which has large amount of data to be handled. i have inserted around 10 million of data into mongoDb database. Now when i am fetching all the data at same time through ajax, request is taking too much time to fetch the data. so what to do make data load fast?

```
router.get('/ekcroredata', async (req, res)=>{
const data = await gameBids.find();
res.json(data);});
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to send all the data to the client in one go. Response time will depend on the size of the data. instead you should implement pagination. Fetch the records in a bunch of fixed size by calling the same API repeatedly.

```
router.get('/ekcroredata', async (req, res)=>{
  let { page_number, page_size } = req.query; // keep increasing the page_number in the successive call by client
  const data = await gameBids.find().skip((page_number)*page_size).limit(page_size)
  res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: i was thinking the same, but  is there any alternative ?

Comment: you can use stream api from nodejs

Answer (score -3):

Actually node js is not feasible to handle large data so you have two options

1. Use pagination
2. Use python for huge data related operation

Comment: I think nodejs can handle large amount of data also it depend on how you write it python if you write it incorrectly it will be slow also.